# Deleting a row selected in datagrid from database in c#

Tags: c#

How can I delete a particular row selected in grid from data table.
I tried with this code.

```
 string s1 = null;


      int i = datagridInfoOrg.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            datagridInfoOrg.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            datagridInfoOrg.Refresh();


        string s = "Select * from Add_Information";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(s, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            s1 = dr[i].ToString();


        }
        cmd1.Dispose();
        dr.Dispose();
        string Query = "delete from Add_Information WHERE CompanyName='"+s1+"'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);


        //conDatabase.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Succesfully Updated !!");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No row selected");
        }
```

by this code only first row is deleting, but not the selected row.
Can any one help me out??

Answer (score 1):

Your line `s1 = dr[i].ToString();` will always give you the i-th column for the first row as you have only performed the first `dr.Read()`

Comment: How about something like

int i=0;
while (dr.Read())
{
 if (count == i++) { s1 = ... }

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your logic is wrong.

[`SqlDataReader.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method read your reader row by row. That means when you write `dr[i].ToString()` in an *if statement* (not like *while statement*), this code works just one time and reads the *i-th* number cell **of your first row**. That's why it is too normal to delete your first row.

But since we don't know what is the value of `i` in your code, not possible to assuming more.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach to get the cell data from the selected row as shown below. The idea here is not to go by a index by to get the cell value and use the value in a delete query so the value from the cell would be used to get the row in the DataTable or simply go right to the table in the database and remove one or more rows matching the company name found in the DataGridView.

```
/// <summary>
/// In the case there is a column in the DataGridView
/// named CompanyNameColumn
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void cmdRemoveDataGridViewRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // make sure we have a row to work with
    if (!datagridInfoOrg.CurrentRow.IsNewRow)
    {
        // use this value for your query
        string KeyValue = datagridInfoOrg
            .CurrentRow
            .Cells["CompanyNameColumn"]
            .Value
            .ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(KeyValue))
        {
            // row index for current row
            // int rowIndex = datagridInfoOrg.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            // do your delete and would suggest using a parameterized
            // query especially if there is a chance of embedded apostrophe
            // in the cell value
            datagridInfoOrg.Rows.Remove(datagridInfoOrg.CurrentRow);
        }
        else
        {
            // recovery code in the event the value in the cell
            // was not valid.
        }
    }
}
```